# Looping through multiple netcdf files to read the data

Tags: python, loops, geolocation, netcdf, netcdf4

I want to read through multiple netCDF (a succession of days) files to read the data in order to make a SO2 flux time series from volcanoes. To do that I think I need to create a loop. But I am not sure how to do that.

```
    all_files = ['S5P_OFFL_L2__SO2____20181222T113340_20181222T131510_06173_01_010105_20181228T221109.nc', 'S5P_OFFL_L2__SO2____20181223T111438_20181223T125608_06187_01_010105_20181229T211412.nc']
filename = 'C:/Users/Frank van der Leij/OneDrive/Documenten/BSc_python/Etna/S5P_OFFL_L2__SO2____20181224T105537_20181224T123707_06201_01_010105_20181230T202633.nc'
fid = Dataset(filename,'r')
lon1 = fid.groups['PRODUCT'].groups['SUPPORT_DATA'].groups['GEOLOCATIONS'].variables['longitude_bounds'][:,:,:,0]
lon2 = fid.groups['PRODUCT'].groups['SUPPORT_DATA'].groups['GEOLOCATIONS'].variables['longitude_bounds'][:,:,:,1]
lon3 = fid.groups['PRODUCT'].groups['SUPPORT_DATA'].groups['GEOLOCATIONS'].variables['longitude_bounds'][:,:,:,2]
lon4 = fid.groups['PRODUCT'].groups['SUPPORT_DATA'].groups['GEOLOCATIONS'].variables['longitude_bounds'][:,:,:,3]
lat1 = fid.groups['PRODUCT'].groups['SUPPORT_DATA'].groups['GEOLOCATIONS'].variables['latitude_bounds'][:,:,:,0]
lat2 = fid.groups['PRODUCT'].groups['SUPPORT_DATA'].groups['GEOLOCATIONS'].variables['latitude_bounds'][:,:,:,1]
lat3 = fid.groups['PRODUCT'].groups['SUPPORT_DATA'].groups['GEOLOCATIONS'].variables['latitude_bounds'][:,:,:,2]
lat4 = fid.groups['PRODUCT'].groups['SUPPORT_DATA'].groups['GEOLOCATIONS'].variables['latitude_bounds'][:,:,:,3]
lon5 = fid.groups['PRODUCT'].variables['longitude'][:]
lat5 = fid.groups['PRODUCT'].variables['latitude'][:]
sza = fid.groups['PRODUCT'].groups['SUPPORT_DATA'].groups['GEOLOCATIONS'].variables['solar_zenith_angle'][:]
SO2VCD = fid.groups['PRODUCT'].groups['SUPPORT_DATA'].groups['DETAILED_RESULTS'].variables['sulfurdioxide_total_vertical_column_7km'][:]
secs = fid.groups['PRODUCT'].variables['delta_time'][:]
row = fid.groups['PRODUCT'].variables['ground_pixel'][:]
SO2SCDcor = fid.groups['PRODUCT'].groups['SUPPORT_DATA'].groups['DETAILED_RESULTS'].variables['sulfurdioxide_slant_column_corrected'][:]*2241.15
fid.close()
```

Do I create a variable like i did with all files. And then loop through that array? Does it read all the lon data from all files and assign it to one variable?

I am new to Python so it may be a simple solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps module `xarray` can be used? Or `MFDataset` from `netCDF4`? Usually, I am using `xarray.open_mfdataset(pathin+fsuffixin+'*')` to read data over multiple files. Module `netCDF4` is somehow simpler to use, but somehow in my cases so far, `MFDataset` is not working properly. Therefore have used `xarray`.

Comment: Yes MFDataset does not work properly with NetCDF4 format. So I also think I have to use xarray. But that merges all data sets into one right? I have about 15 files of 750Mb each, would that then still work?

Comment: I think it only merges metadata and not the data itself until you load it to memory. So, as with netCDF4 following command: `data = ncin.variables['varname'][:]` automatically loads the data, with xarray you do: `data = ncin.variables['varname'][:].load()`. Without load() it is not loaded and you can always do a loop. Something like:
`for itime in range(len(time)): data = ncin.variables['varname'][itime,:].load()`
to save memory.